# Axios reporting "undefined" 1000s of times a day

Tags: node.js, ajax, vue.js, axios, cors

## TLDR

We're getting thousands of `undefined` responses from our network requests a day, which makes up 80-90% of our total number of error events in Sentry (per day). I've read a lot of threads about "Network Error" with Axios, but I believe we're getting this volume of errors because our server/node application is failing that many times a day.

## About Us

We have 1000 active daily users, with anywhere from 10-20 concurrents users on the entire application at any given time between 10 AM - 5 PM.

We use Sentry to log every error on every single request made on the FE (we use a try...catch block system and in every catch block, there's a Sentry request made to report that error).

## Our problem

We get about 4000 error events a day (very high, I know), but 3200, or roughly 80%, are reported with a `response: [undefined]`. This has made it impossible to actually find and solve real errors our users are experiencing, unless they report it directly to us.

I'm aware of the many conversations about "Network Error" with Axios, since Axios can't consistenly report accurately when there's a network error in the browser, but something is clearly causing this error to occurs thousands of times a day for a low number of users.

Some additional info that may be help:

- It occasionally occurs when running the application locally, but there's no difference in the error reported in the browser.
- We've tried up'ing the power of our servers and telling our application to use more power, but that didn't even reduce the errors a little.
- Every now and then, the error on my local reports a CORS issue, or that CORS failed.
- There's no limit to the request this can happen on, but obviously, we see it more on requests that are made more often.
- The request doesn't seem to be related to a browser or mobile vs desktop.

## What I'm hoping to find

I believe there's nothing wrong with Axios. I'm wondering if we have CORS improperly configured in a way that only a low percentage of the time causes an error or we have improperly configured Axios or something on our backend that's causing our server/system/whatever to crash A LOT.

Any experience or ideas would be greatly appreciated! We're plagued by this.

Here's a look at our `axiosConfig.js`:

```
// This is copied to /marketing-website/utils/api/api-service
// If it needs updated for any reason, please update /marketing-website if applicable
// Packages
import axios from 'axios'
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
// Helpers
import { getCurrentJWTToken } from './cognito'
import { CError } from './consoleMixin'

const BASE_API = async () => {
  const jwtToken = await getCurrentJWTToken()
  return {
    headers: {
      authorization: jwtToken,
      indempotency: uuidv4(),
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
  }
}

// we don't necessarily want to hit the same base url every time, if we use other apis
// this is a place we can initialize the headers we send everywhere as well
const API = async () => {
  const api = axios.create({
    ...await BASE_API(),
  })
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent
  // If user is on Edge or IE, return now
  if (userAgent.includes('Trident') || userAgent.includes('Edge')) {
    return api
  }
  // Breaks login on Edge/IE
  api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.metadata = { startTime: new Date() }
    // If a controlledClient currently exists, send their information to the backend
    const controlledClient = localStorage.getItem('controlledClient')
    if (controlledClient) {
      if (!config.params) {
        config.params = { controlledClientUser: JSON.parse(controlledClient).id }
      } else {
        const configParams = config.params
        configParams.controlledClientUser = JSON.parse(controlledClient).id
        config.params = configParams
      }
    }

    return config
  }, (error) => {
    this.CError(error)
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })
  api.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      response.config.metadata.endTime = new Date()
      response.duration = response.config.metadata.endTime - response.config.metadata.startTime
      // CLog('request and time:', response.config.url, response.duration)
      try {
        // remove any id numbers from the end since we're grouping by API call type
        const urlSplits = response.config.url.split('/');
        const last = urlSplits[urlSplits.length - 1]
        const url = isNaN(last)
          ? response.config.url
          : response.config.url.split(`/${last}`)[0]

        let role = 'UNAUTHENTICATED';
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        if (user && user.employee) role = 'EMPLOYEE'
        if (user && user.client) role = 'CLIENT'
        if (window.ga) {
          window.ga('send', {
            hitType: 'timing',
            timingCategory: `API REQUEST ${role} ${response.config.method.toUpperCase()}`,
            timingVar: url,
            timingValue: response.duration,
            label: url
          })
        }
      } catch (err) {
        CError('Error with google analytics', err)
      }
      return response
    },
    (error) => {
      CError('GENERAL ERROR:', error)
      error.config.metadata.endTime = new Date()
      error.duration = error.config.metadata.endTime - error.config.metadata.startTime
      CError('AXIOS ERROR:', error.config, error.response)

      try {
        CError('Stringified:', JSON.stringify(error))
      } catch (err) {
        CError('Error with stringify error')
      }
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        if (
          error.response.data.message.includes === 'User not found'
          || error.response.data.name === 'AuthError')
        {
          window.open('/login', '_self')
        }
      }
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  );
  const retryDelay = (retryNumber = 0) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-properties
    const seconds = Math.pow(2, retryNumber) * 1000;
    const randomMs = 1000 * Math.random();
    return seconds + randomMs;
  };
  axiosRetry(api, {
    retries: 3,
    retryDelay,
    // retry on Network Error
    retryCondition: axiosRetry.isNetworkError,
  });
  return api
}

export default API
```

Here is a stack trace on my local:
[image]

Comment: > "It occasionally occurs when running the application locally" -- can you at least get a stack trace?

Comment: One of the URLs returned by `BASE_URL()` could have improper CORS config.

Comment: @user202729 I'll do my best getting one soon.

Comment: @user202729 Added

Comment: Well yep, that's a CORS error alright.